# Jetty returns 400 when URI has 2 slashes in a row while Tomcat doesn't care

Tags: tomcat, jetty

I have a client that makes a request that looks something like this:

https://app.foo.com/foo//bar/baz/

When my foo war is hosted in tomcat that URL resolves and returns whatever it is supposed to.  I recently tried running the same war file in jetty and when run in jetty the same URI returns a 400 bad request.  Is there any way to configure Jetty to not care about this, and if it sees 2+ slashes in a row in the URL to just treat it as if it is just 1 slash, the way Tomcat does?

Answer (score 1):

Per the URI specs, that is considered an "ambiguous empty path segment" and as such the default configuration in Jetty returns "400 Bad Path" when it sees them.

There are many parts of the URI spec that result in ambiguous interpretation, and all of them are specified in the Jetty `UriCompliance.Violation`.

See:

- https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3
- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-11.0.12/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/UriCompliance.java#L40-L72

The following are UriCompliance violations that can be enabled/disabled.

| Key | Description | Spec Reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `AMBIGUOUS_PATH_SEGMENT` | Allow ambiguous path segments e.g. `/foo/%2e%2e/bar` | [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) |
| `AMBIGUOUS_EMPTY_SEGMENT` | Allow ambiguous empty segments e.g. `//` | [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) |
| `AMBIGUOUS_PATH_SEPARATOR` | Allow ambiguous path separator within a URI segment e.g. `/foo/b%2fr` | [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) |
| `AMBIGUOUS_PATH_PARAMETER` | Allow ambiguous path parameters within a URI segment e.g. `/foo/..;/bar` or `/foo/%2e%2e;param/bar` | [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) |
| `AMBIGUOUS_PATH_ENCODING` | Allow ambiguous path encoding within a URI segment e.g. `/%2557EB-INF` | [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) |
| `UTF16_ENCODINGS` | Allow UTF-16 encoding eg `/foo%u2192bar` | [w3c/draft-duerst-iri](https://www.w3.org/International/iri-edit/draft-duerst-iri.html#anchor29) |

The `UriCompliance` is configured in the `HttpConfiguration` that your `ServerConnector` classes use.

If you choose to allow these via the `UriCompliance` configuration, know that all you are doing is allowing them to proceed into Jetty.

That configuration does no compaction of the path segments.
This is because many users that care about empty path segments, actually want the extra empty path segments for tools like gRPC, REST, and the like which will honor the empty segments.

Jetty offers a compaction option, in the form of a `RewriteHandler` and it's `CompactPathRule`.

The servlet spec expert group itself recently had a conversation about these ambiguous path behaviors specified in RFC3986, but didn't cover the specific case you have of `//`.

- https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/issues/18

Comment: I don't believe the OP's example URI is ambiguous at all according to RFC3986; as I read them, both [the ABNF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#appendix-A) and [the regex](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#appendix-B) unambiguously identify the path in the OP's example as the five segments `"foo"`, `""`, `"bar"`, `"baz"`, `""`.

Comment: @MarkSlater if you run your server in RFC3986 (default in Jetty 10+) mode you'll see that, but it that mode can also run into issues when it reaches the Servlet spec (you cannot create url-patterns for empty path segments, either in mapping the context path, a servlet, a filter, or even a constraint).  But it doesn't help the OP which is wanting the broken "fix" that Tomcat does and ignoring empty path segments.